# Integer |= Char; operation ignoring high order byte in Integer

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Just a quick and specific question, this has stumped me for half an hour almost.

```
char * bytes = {0x01, 0xD8};
int value = 0;

value = bytes[0];  // result is 1 (0x0001)
value <<= 8;       // result is 256 (0x0100)
value |= bytes[1]; // result is -40? (0xFFD8) How is this even happening?
```

The last operation is the one of interest to me, how is it turning a signed integer of 256 into -40?

**edit**: changed a large portion of the example code for brevity

Comment: What are the types of `buffer` and `value`?

Comment: This code is a bit too 'pseudo' for the question to be answered IMO.

Comment: @Mu - `buffer` is a `char *` and `value` is a `int`

Comment: I'd guess that it's sign extending the value on the right (`D8`) before the or operation occurs, to make the operands on both sides the same length.

Comment: @Karl - It mimics the source 1 for 1 except where the 'pseudo' comment appears, which omits how buffer is allocated.  Really, that all is just fluff context for the final three lines of code, which is where the problem seems to emerge

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - ... you are right.  That was the problem.  Casting to an unsigned char prevents it from doing that.  Aha!  So, what's the protocol when a question is answered in the comments?

Comment: It was mostly a guess, but I then googled around for char to int sign extension to confirm it, and have now posted an answer, but @Roland's answer may be more complete.

Comment: Never use signed types together with the bitwise operators - the answer to the question is simple as that.

Comment: @Alf - The complete code would involve hundreds of lines of stream parsing code.  If I made any mistake, it was including as much code as I did.  The question's already answered, but I'll snip that large portion out.

Comment: @Lundin - I assumed bitwise operations treated the sign as just another bit, but live and learn indeed!

Comment: @Clairvoire They do. The problem isn't the bitwise operators by themselves, but the dangerous implicit type promotion rules of the C language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case the type `char` is equivalent to `signed char`, which means that when you save the value `0xD8` in a `char`, it will come out as a negative number.

The *usual arithmetic conversions* that happen during the `|=` operation are value-preserving, so the negative number is preserved.

To solve the problem, you can either make all your data types `unsigned` when you have binary arithmetics. Or you can write `value |= ((unsigned char) buffer[0])` or `value |= buffer[0] & 0xFF`.

Comment: To be picky, the integer promotions are what makes bytes[1] a (signed) int with the sign preserved. Though they are part of the usual arithmetic conversions.

Comment: This code isn't mine, not sure why anyone would not use `unsigned char` to begin with, but the cast solves my problem pretty handedly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to perform the `|=` operation, we need the operands on both sides to be the same size. Since `char` is smaller than `int`, it has to be converted to an `int`. But, since `char` is a signed type, it's expanded to an `int` by sign extension.

That is, `D8` becomes `FFD8` before the or operation even happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the problem, here char is a signed character (216) but the signed character can store the value in between (-128,127) that means 216 (11011000) Most significant bit is 1 that is this is a negative number which 2's compliment is 00101000 which is equivalent to -40

when you doing this
 value |= bytes[1];

in that case actually you are taking OR of 256 , -40

(256 | -40) is equal to -40